# Statement not covered - not able to go inside the function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am having following method in functional component:

```
  const handleClickOutside = (e: CustomEvent) => {
    if (dropdownRef.current!.contains(e.target as Node)) {
      return;
    }
    changeFocusedElement(findSelectedItemIndex());
    setShowList(!showList);
  };
```

I am trying to test it like:

```
  it('Hides list after call handleClickOutside method', () => {
    const outerNode = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(outerNode);

    const WrappingComponent = (props: { children: React.ReactElement }) => (
      withTestTheme(props.children)
    );
    const wrapper = mount(
      <SelectNew options={testOptions} value="test" />,
      {
        wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent,
      },
    );
    wrapper.find('.dropdown__field').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('ul').exists()).toBe(true);

    outerNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));

    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('ul').exists()).toBe(false);
  });
```

but I am not able to go inside the function which is shown in test coverage report:

[image]

Below how the function is called:

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (showList) {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
      } else {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
      }

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
      };
    },
    [showList],
  );
```

Any idea how to go inside the function?

Comment: Did you called `handleClickOutside` ?

Comment: @brk See update, inserted the code.